# Interpreting Python profiler

Tags: python, profiling, spyder

[image]

I'm using profiler in Spyder IDE to profile a simple program.  One of the functions, `make_geology` is the piggiest part of the code.  It appears to use 24.7 time units (are they seconds?).  But when I look at all the calls made from within `make_geology` (everything I've highlighted in yellow), that sum of time only adds up to 1.3 time units.

Am I misundertanding the measurement and allocation of time spent in functions? I would have thought time spent in make_geology = sum of time spent on all the things inside make_geology

Comment: Have you tried [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)? For one thing, it is sensitive to percents, not absolute measurements, so it directly tells you what's piggy. It also tells you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that make_geology has some functionality that is done inside the function call itself, not "offloaded" to other components (functions). Imagine something like this:

```
def add_and_count(mylist, mynumber):
  i = 0
  while i < mynumber:
      i = i + 1
  mylist.append(i)
```

If mynumber is 0, the time to execute add_and_count should be about the same as the time to execute list's append call. If mynumber is huge, the list.append would be a drop in the bucket

Answer (score 1):

I have provided [this PR](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/3741) to solve this trouble.

At the beginning the profiler looks like this:
[image: profiler_before]

The final result looks like this:
[image: spyder 3 1 0 dev0 python 3 5 _001]

Any suggestions or corrections are welcome.

Best Regards

William Trigos